# Z-index issue with sibling children

Tags: css

***A lot of time was wasted creating this ticket, having it being marked as a duplicate, by a person who didn't bother to look at the issue and see that they are in fact NOT related.
What a great use of my time this was.***

So I've been through quite some documentation trying to find a solution to this problem, but currently I'm out of ideas.

**The issue:** I have a top navigation, below this, I have an iFrame. The navigation has a button which will trigger a dropdown, now this dropdown does not disappear when hovering out of it, and this is important for the following.

*I want to create a scenario where the iFrame is above the navigation, but below the dropdown.*

This should not imo not have been a big issue, but I ran into the following issue.

- Dropdown is a child of the navigation, and seems to inherit the z-index, so if the dropdown z-index is set to 41, and the navigation to 30, i would imagine, you had something like this **30.41** and making the iFrame z-index 30 I thought **30.00**. However, it seems there is a "hidden (at least to me)" stacking context going on. They are in fact **30.0.41** and **30.1.0** which means the iFrame is on top of both.

Not really sure how to get around this, I made a fiddle, and the second example works, but that expects Nav and iFrame to be actual siblings, and they are not (only visually).

Tried thoroughly reading this, but no luck:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

https://jsfiddle.net/s0j5mLp6/3/

```css
.test1 {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}

.nav {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 30;
}

.dropdown {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background: darkred;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 40;
   top: 70px;
   left: 70px;
}

.iframe {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background:  blue;
  opacity: 0.7;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 30;
  top: 100px;
  will-change: z-index;
}

.test2 {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}

.nav2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
}

.dropdown2 {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background: darkred;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 40;
   top: 70px;
   left: 70px;
}

.iframe2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background:  blue;
  opacity: 0.7;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  will-change: z-index;
}
```

```html
<div class="test1">
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="dropdown"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="iframe"></div>
</div>

<div class="test2">
  <div class="nav2">
    <div class="dropdown2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="iframe2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: add `position: relative` to css for class `test1`.

Comment: remove z-index from nav (don't specify any there)